# Reusing Fragment to an Activity but with some modified data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am studying about how to use fragments from Udacity's Android Tutorials. I had a dilemma. 
Let's say, I have an activity A, which consists of a Frame Layout. I add a fragment B(consisting of a TextView TVfrag) to this activity using FragmentManager.
Now is it possible to call fragment B, again (from A), but now with a modified data in its TextView(TVfrag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use it as fragment can be reused. but this time this will be new object not old one. you create new fragment object and then replace it with new data. and don't add previous fragment into back stack.

OR

You can create some method in fragment which will update value of textview on the basis of some event. and make sure your fragment is attached or view is not destroyed. otherwise it will throw null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good approach to update fragments directly from activity. If you are updating text inside your fragment then you should also keep the updation logic inside your fragment. Make your fragments loosely coupled with activity so that it can be used with other activities. 
According to Google -

[image]

Read more - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html?hl=ru